# How to upload csv file and store it to folder in my server using datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I have table and make the datatable on it, I added download csv file on it and it's working. Now, I need to upload the same file or store it in some folder path.

This is my code for datatable

```
$('#account_details').DataTable({
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    lengthMenu: [
        [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500 -1 ],
        [ '10', '25', '50', '100', '250', '500' ]
    ],
    pageLength: 10,
    buttons: [
        { 
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text:'', 
            className: 'excelbtn',
            filename: 'Account_details', 
            title: 'Account Details', 
            titleAttr: 'Excel', 
            exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
        }, { 
            extend: 'pdfHtml5', 
            text:'',
            className: 'pdfbtn',
            filename: 'Account_details', 
            title: 'Account Details', 
            titleAttr: 'PDF', 
            exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
        }, { 
            extend: 'print',
            text:'',
            className: 'print',
            filename: 'Account_details', 
            title: 'Account Details', 
            titleAttr: 'Print', 
            exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
        }, { 
            extend: 'csv', 
            text:'',
            className: 'csv',
            filename: 'Account_details', 
            title: 'Account Details', 
            titleAttr: 'Reports', 
            exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
        }
    ],
    responsive: true,
    colReorder: true,
    stateSave:  true,
    stateSaveCallback: function(settings, data) {
        console.log(data);
        update_customize_table_settings('account_details','accounts');
    }
});
```

My problem is:
Need to search for some records from frontend using datatable and store the result in another table in the db . i stored the results on csv file and downloaded it . i just to extract data from that file and store it in the another table in db and display it .

Please can anyone help me ?

Comment: Lots of steps... here's a good article on how to approach it https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: No, i don't need to upload file manually.

i need to do it dynamically after click on button ,
 
my  problem is:
i need search on some records from frontend using datatable and store the result in another table in the db .

i stored the results on csv file  and downloaded it .
i just to extract data from that file and store it in the another table in db and display it .

Comment: I think instead of downloading csv,uploading it,parsing it and inserting in db table. What you should do is put another button which user can press after searching and on pressing the button, the searched records will get added to db table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a button which user will click on after searching.

   ```
                   initComplete: function () {
                       $("div.toolbar").html(
                           '<a href="#" class="btn  btn-info btn-secondary" style="margin: 5px" id="insertbtn" onclick="InsertRows()">Insert</a>');
                   }
   ```
2. InsertRows function

   ```
          function InsertRows() {

               var table = $("#dtexample").DataTable();
               var data = table.rows().data();
               data.each(function (value, index) {
                   console.log(`For index ${index}, data value is ${value}`);
                   console.dir(value);
                   //call AJAX below to insert each row to table
               });

           }
   ```

   This will make n number of insert AJAX requests which is fine if you're inserting small number of rows. But if the searched number of rows are greater, then I would advice to add the data to an array and POST array to Webservice to insert it into table.